# How to apply "With UR" clause in existing Hql or SQL queries? How can I append this in Java file where my query is in string format

Tags: db2, hql

So I have this SQL query in one of the Java files as follows: (I am giving the sample & not the real one)

```
@Query( "Select T1.ID" +
    ", T1.CD" +
    ", T1.Date" +
    ", T1.Name" +
    " From Table1 T1" +
    " Join Table2 T2 " +
    " On T1.ID = T2.ID" +
    " Where T1.CD in 
    ("test1","test2")" +
    " And NOT EXISTS" +
    "      (Select 1 From Table2 T3" 
    +
    "       Where T3.ID = T1.ID +
    "       And T3.Name NOT 
    IN('P','Q','R')"+
    "    )")
    List<Object[]> methodToRetrieve 
    (@Param("sequence")String 
    sequence,@Param("code") code);
```

Can someone please tell me where can I add "With UR" in the above query.

Comment: This isn't mysql code so I have removed that tag

Comment: I would ask why do you need `WITH UR` in the first place. Though there are valid use cases for it, it's used too much, too frequently for cases that don't really need it.

Answer (score 2):

PSA: include your Db2 platform/version in your posts; also consider using a platform specific db2 tag if applicable (db2-luw or db2i)

The `isolation-clause` appears after the `fullselect` in the documentation
[image]

so your code should be

```
@Query( "Select T1.ID" +
    ", T1.CD" +
    ", T1.Date" +
    ", T1.Name" +
    " From Table1 T1" +
    " Join Table2 T2 " +
    " On T1.ID = T2.ID" +
    " Where T1.CD in 
    ("test1","test2")" +
    " And NOT EXISTS" +
    "      (Select 1 From Table2 T3" 
    +
    "       Where T3.ID = T1.ID +
    "       And T3.Name NOT 
    IN('P','Q','R')"+
    "    ) WITH UR")
    List<Object[]> methodToRetrieve 
    (@Param("sequence")String 
    sequence,@Param("code") code);
```